# Send byte slice in inline attachment with Mailgun

Tags: go, mailgun

I'm using the [Mailgun package](https://github.com/mailgun/mailgun-go) for Go and would like to send an inline image using cid. In my html template for mailgun I have the correct `cid:qr-code.png` set up. However I have to add an inline attachment to my email with the qr code. I use the [this](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/skip2/go-qrcode#Encode) method to generate a QR code:

```
code, err := qrcode.Encode(data, qrcode.Medium, 256) // code is a []byte
```

Now I need to add this code to my email as an inline attachment with the cid property set to `qr-code.png`

The [`message.AddBufferAttachment("qr-code.png", code)`](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/mailgun/mailgun-go#Message.AddBufferAttachment) correctly attaches the image, but does not inline it because I can't set the `cid` property.

Now I know this is possible with mailgun because the following code in .js can accomplish it using mailgun.

```
mg.Attachment({
  data: base64Buffer,
  filename: "qr-code.png",
  cid: "cid:qr-code.png",
}),
```

I just can't seem to do it with the go Mailgun package. **Note:** I can't write the image to a file and on the os and then attach it.

Comment: Did you try `message.AddReaderInline(filename string, readCloser io.ReadCloser) `?

Comment: @Tyger Yes, but I can't figure out how to convert []bytes to an io.ReadCloser. `bytes.NewReader` converts to an `io.Reader` not an `io.ReadCloser`.

Comment: You can convert it to an `io.Reader` and then to an `io.ReadCloser` like this `ioutil.NopCloser(bytes.NewReader(code))`

Comment: @Tyger It Worked!! If you add an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: Sounds good. Make sure to test it thoroughly I've never actually used mailgun before

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the the `AddReaderInline` function

`message.AddReaderInline(filename, readCloser)`

Since you need to convert `[]bytes` to `io.ReadCloser` you can convert to `io.Reader` then to `io.ReadCloser`

`ioutil.NopCloser(bytes.NewReader(code))`